# How to remove random excess of slashes from url?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, gsub, slash

How to remove random excess of slashes from url or just validate it?

For example,

**valid statements**:

> http://domain.com/url/url2
>
> https://domain.com/url/url2
>
> www.domain.com/url/url2

**invalid statements:**

> http://domain.com//url/url2
>
> https://domain.com/////url/url2
>
> www.domain.com/url/////////url2

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use regular expressions:

```
require 'uri'
url = URI.parse('https://domain.com/////url/url2')
url.path.gsub! %r{/+}, '/'
p url.to_s
```

Comment: yeap, thanks.
but this will not work correctly for "http://", 'cause it have 2 slashes

Comment: this would collapse the essential double slash after the schema portion (eg. `https://`) too, wouldn't it ? better use `%r{([^:/])/+}, '$1/'`.

Comment: Ah, yes.  Fixed to only do the path.

Comment: Nice approach! Thanks, Sam!

Comment: Works alright, I prefer to use squeeze instead of gsub (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-squeeze), `url.path.squeeze!("/")`

Answer (score 1):

this pattern do the job (with http(s) or not) :

```
"https://domain.com/////url/url2".gsub! %r{(?<!:)/+(?=/)}, ''
```

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do not remove a **trailing slash** from the URL - which can be important for SEO purposes. There are many ways to do this, but for example:

```
require 'uri'
url = URI.parse('https://example.com/////url/url2/')
url.path.gsub! %r{/+}, '/'
url.path.sub! %r{/$}, ''
```

Or:

```
require 'uri'
url = URI.parse('https://example.com/////url/url2/')
url.path.squeeze!('/')
url.path.chomp!('/')
```

See: [`String#squeeze!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-squeeze-21) and [`String#chomp!`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-chomp-21).